# angularjs default page without having to type index.html

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating an angularjs app with VS 2017 community. When I run the app locally I get the localhost with port in the address bar but it doesn't take me to index.html by default. If I type index.html in then it works, but since all routing goes through the angular app which is hooked up in index.html this ruins routing. I can't type localhost:portnumber/my_other_route_here since it then doesn't go through the angularjs app defined in index.html. How do I get IISExpress to do this automatic routing to index.html without having to type index.html?

I have the following in my config file and thought it would help with that and has in the past so not sure what is different this time.

```
<!-- Must have this so that direct entries in the browsers address bar get routed correctly. This routes entires that don't have physical paths to index.htm which
    will route it correctly if a path is setup. Basically this allows for pretty url's like localhost:1234/red -->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="angularjs routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <!-- END rules -->
```

Answer (score 0):

So I used the default ASP.NET Application template for Web API (Not MVC) but it adds MVC anyway. The fact that it had a RegisterRoutes() which was doing some mapping seems to be why this was happening. When I comment out everything in here (can probably delete the entire file) then by default it would open index.html without having to put it in the address bar.